# Emmc replace (inbuilt memory card mounter) with external memory card mounter

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card, hardware, customization

Hi friends i want to increase inbuilt memory at infinity level by replacing Emmc holder (inbuilt memory card mounter) with external memory card mounter, can it be possible? If yes how? If NO Why??

Answer (score 1):

There's more to just internal storage in eMMC - it holds a vast array of partitions. Here's an example I just got from my phone.

[image]

As you can see many of those "blocks" (mmcblk_p_) correspond to major functions of the phone. Even more, such as EFS (stores baseband info) and sbl* (bootloader) aren't even listed here because they're even more crucial, are loaded at boot time, and doesn't allow a regular user to tinker with.

Now imagine all those partitions *all* shifted to an external, removable source. With proprietary formats, is it possible in the first place? Even if yes, what if one removes the media in the middle of booting up?

And lastly, eMMCs (and recently-introduced UFS2s) are significantly faster than your average SD card. Running Android on a Class 4 SD card is actually a painful experience - if you don't believe it, burn Android-x86 onto an SD card and try booting from it.

Comment: But sir if we remove card in middle of booting system hanges  or stopped, just like a raspberry pie....ya it may hamper system but still I need to know how to replace it??

Comment: "with proprietary formats" - try and see if an SD card can have so many partitions of different and sometimes proprietary format.

Comment: Not understood, yes raspberry pie is proprietor formats but it's not restricting us to understand the concept of how?

Comment: @user190688 Out of my league, so I'll leave this up to someone else who's more knowledgeable. There are possible explanations but they're all just my speculations so I'd not bother confusing you with those.

Comment: To others: feel free to edit this if you have the privilege.